# wxpython How to prevent BoxSizer from collapsing when window is resized?

Tags: python, c++, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am using BoxSizer as a horizontal and vertical layout. However when I use a vertical `BoxSizer` in a horizontal `BoxSizer` to contain my buttons so it display vertically beside another element, and when you resize it, it collapse and hide the buttons until you expand it again.

Here is what it looks like by default
[image]

and here is how it looks like after we resize it to a smaller width
[image]

As you can see, the buttons is collapsed when resized. How do you stop BoxSizer from being collapsed whenever the window is resized?

[Code](https://github.com/ojiii/neko/blob/master/neko/mainframe.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the semi-rigid rule of posting your code in the question, not on a link, is so that people can see if you have changed it, which you have!

Your code has now changed, so it becomes difficult to explain changes made to the original code and how they relate to the new code.

Basically, you have to pay special attention, when using sizers, to the proportion and wx.EXPAND flags. They can cause all sorts of unintended consequences.

Personally, I would probably have run with a different sizer, perhaps `FlexGridSizer` for this.

Here is your original code, with the `proportion` and expand `flags` adjusted to perform what I assume you wanted.

```
import wx
from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin

#from processor import process_xls

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    TITLE = 'Neko'
    FRAME_MIN_SIZE = (600, 300)
    DEFAULT_BORDER_SIZE = 10

    INPUT_LABEL = 'Input files : '
    ADD_LABEL = 'Add'

    REMOVE_LABEL = 'Remove'
    START_LABEL = 'Start'

    FILE_LABEL = 'File'
    SIZE_LABEL = 'Size'
    PERCENT_LABEL = 'Percent'
    ETA_LABEL = 'ETA'
    SPEED_LABEL = 'Speed'
    STATUS_LABEL = 'Status'
    STATUS_LIST = {
        'filename': (0, FILE_LABEL, 120, True),
        'size': (1, SIZE_LABEL, 60, False),
        'percent': (2, PERCENT_LABEL, 80, False),
        'eta': (3, ETA_LABEL, 60, False),
        'speed': (4, SPEED_LABEL, 60, False),
        'status': (5, STATUS_LABEL, 90, False),
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.SetTitle(self.TITLE)
        self.SetSize(self.FRAME_MIN_SIZE)

        self._panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self._vertical_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Inputs
        self._horizontal_box_input = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self._tc_file_picker = wx.TextCtrl(self._panel)
        self._horizontal_box_input.Add(self._tc_file_picker,
                                    proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self._button_add = wx.Button(self._panel,
                                label=self.ADD_LABEL,
                                size=(-1,-1))
        self._button_add.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,
                            self._on_add)
        self._horizontal_box_input.Add(self._button_add,
                                    flag=wx.LEFT,
                                    border=self.DEFAULT_BORDER_SIZE)

        self._vertical_box.Add(self._horizontal_box_input,
                            flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP,
                            border=self.DEFAULT_BORDER_SIZE)

        # Status List
        self._status_list = ListCtrl(self.STATUS_LIST,
                                parent=self._panel,
                                style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT)
        self._horizontal_box_status_list = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self._horizontal_box_status_list.Add(self._status_list,
                                        proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        status_list_buttons_data = {
            ('remove', self.REMOVE_LABEL, (-1, -1), self._on_remove, wx.Button),
            ('start', self.START_LABEL, (-1, -1), self._on_start, wx.Button),
        }

        # Create buttons vertically
        self._vertical_control_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        for item in status_list_buttons_data:
            name, label, size, evt_handler, parent = item

            button = parent(self._panel, size=size)

            if parent == wx.Button:
                button.SetLabel(label)

            if evt_handler is not None:
                button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, evt_handler)

            self._vertical_control_box.Add(button,
                                        flag=wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND,
                                        proportion=1,
                                        border=self.DEFAULT_BORDER_SIZE)

        self._horizontal_box_status_list.Add(self._vertical_control_box)

        self._vertical_box.Add(self._horizontal_box_status_list,
                            flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP,
                            border=self.DEFAULT_BORDER_SIZE)

        # Set Sizer
        self._panel.SetSizerAndFit(self._vertical_box)

        #If you want the listctrl and textctrl to have a minimum size
        #open_size = self.GetSize()
        #self.SetMinSize(open_size)

        self.Show()

    def _on_add(self, event):
        pass

    def _on_remove(self, event):
        pass

    def _on_start(self, event):
        pass

class ListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListCtrl, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)

        self.columns = columns
        self._set_columns()

    def _set_columns(self):
        for column_item in sorted(self.columns.values()):
            self.InsertColumn(column_item[0], column_item[1], width=wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER)

            # If the column width obtained from wxLIST_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER
            # is smaller than the minimum allowed column width
            # then set the column width to the minumum allowed size
            if self.GetColumnWidth(column_item[0]) < column_item[2]:
                self.SetColumnWidth(column_item[0], column_item[2])

            # Set auto-resize if enabled
            if column_item[3]:
                self.setResizeColumn(column_item[0])
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

On open:[image]
On expand:[image]
On reduce:[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I have not tried it yet but from your screenshots, it seems to be what I wanted. I will post the code next time, I put a link instead because I thought the code might be too long for a question. Thank you!

Comment: I did change proportions around before but it doesn't seem to do anything. It must be the SetSizerAndFit and the flags.

Answer (score 1):

A sizer just lays out the elements using the available size. If there is not enough of it, the sizer has no choice but to truncate (or even completely hide) some items.

To ensure that this doesn't happen, you must ensure that your window can't be made smaller than its minimal size. This is done with `SetMinClientSize()` which is called by the convenient `SetSizerAndFit()` wrapper, neither of which is used in your code.

Comment: Neither work properly. SetSizerAndFit and SetMinClientSize doesn't prevent the widgets from collapsing. Yes you cannot minimize smaller than what you set but after you expand then making the window smaller, the widget will go back to being collapsed/hidden.

Comment: I don't understand how can expanding and then making the window smaller change the window size. Sizers algorithm is perfectly deterministic and the same window size always results in the same layout.

Comment: What I meant is even if you limit it with the method you suggested, when you resize the window, the widget will collapse when you return to the original size. That's the problem I have right now. I did you solution but the problem still present, the only way to solve this is to not allow resize but that's not a fix.

Comment: It is most likely my lack of knowledge of GUI programming.